# voronoi diagram matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, voronoi

I was wondering how I show/plot a voronoi diagram in the below FCM method? Also is there a method where you can watch the programme from the figure as it places and computes each point in matlab? Almost like a running trailer.

```
  [centers, U, objFun] = fcm(data, 6);
  plot(data(:,1), data(:,2),'o');
  maxU = max(U);
  index1 = find(U(1, :) == maxU);
  index2 = find(U(2, :) == maxU);
  line(data(index1,1),data(index1, 2),'linestyle','none',...
 'marker','*','color','g');
  line(data(index2,1),data(index2, 2),'linestyle','none',...
 'marker', '*','color','r');
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do this without implementing both the clustering and voronoi plots yourself. voronoi use DelaunyTri internally to compute the edges.  Looking at the code for fcm it doesn't use DelaunyTri internally so its going to be hard to hard to come up with cluster edges using DelaunyTri.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be the same for k-means and FCM, btw.

To get the Voronoi diagram, you need to compute the Delaunay triangulation, then place a side of the Voronoi diagram orthogonal on the mean of each Delaunay edge.

There are efficient algorithms for Delaunay in at least 2D and 3D. This is quite closely related to computing the convex hull. Plus, as you don't have many cluster centers, the scalability is not that hard.

However, you have one big problem: your data is 6 dimensional. This means that the sides of your Voronoi cells are in fact 5-dimensional, and they will not trivially map to a reasonable 2d projection.

Computing the Voronoi diagram in the 2D projection that you are using however will be inaccurate. You could try to compute the Voronoi cells in 6D, and map all the corners of the voronoi cells into 2D, then connect neighboring corners. But that may yield a big mess of lines, and is not particularly helpful IMHO.

Sorry, as far as I know, Voronoi cell visualization is mostly useful for understanding k-means in 2D and if you have a good 3D visualization engine in 3D.

Don't get me wrong: **Voronoi cells is exactly what k-means cluster look like**. They're not spheres or blobs or stars. They are Voronoi cells: the cell exactly is the area that would be assigned to a particular mean.

Have a look at this image from Wikipedia:
[image: K-means on wikipedia]

The black lines are the *borders* (which in a 2D data set are simple 1d lines) that separate the clusters. In the top center there is a blue object just right of the line. It is blue, because it is on the right of the line - it is in the Voronoi cell of the blue mean.

This is a key drawback of k-means: it does not have the notion of *size* as in *spatial extend* for a cluster. They only have a center, and the data is split on the orthogonal hyperplane inbetween of two neighboring centers. **For this particular data set, k-means *does not have a chance to split the data correctly!** It hasn't converged to a "bad" local minimum, but the correct solution *cannot* be found by k-means, because the clusters have different size (and there is not enough gap inbetween for k-means to be lucky). To properly cluster this data set, you actually need an EM-like notion of cluster size or a density based method. If k-means were able to detect that the green clusters is about twice as big as the blue ones, it would probably work much better (but then it almost were EM already anyway)

Comment: Thanks Anony, I think I may have been confused with the voronoi diagram. I had watched a tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiJ8II94qck) and read a post on stack with some one who uploaded his k-means figure which had voronoi lines (each figure had been titled voronoi diagram) so I wasnt sure. Reading what you said I dont think this is what I am after. +1

Comment: Voronoi cells are an *excellent* visualization of k-means. When using k-means, one needs to realize that this is the true shape of the clusters found by k-means. Unfortunately, we can't visualize them very well in more than 2d. I'll update the question with an image from Wikipedia that shows the relationship in a minute.

Comment: Thank you for the update on your answer, very informative. Stack need to implement multiple upvotes after a edit! +1